# How to redirect a googleapis link to my website?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, google-api

I saw some googleapis link that directs to a website. I wanted to know how they do it?

The link looks like this one:

http://storage.googleapis.com/7040491591816/1342896388694.html

I need it to look exactly like that with numbers, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the HTML file has a redirect in its header.

So in the HTML doc on the server you would have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://redirect-here.com/">
    </head>

</html>
```

With the `url=""` with whatever site you want it to go to.

The "numbers" you specify are just in the file name of the HTML doc, and the folder it is contained in within Google's cloud storage.

Comment: You need to research Google Cloud Storage Buckets. That will lead you to where you need to put your files.